# How to change the state of properties before event calls?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am using this dialog to display a Create form

```
<p:dialog id="dialogoGestion" header="Asignar nueva gestión" widgetVar="dlg1" >
        <p:ajax event="close" update="dialogoGestion"/>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Cliente: "/>
                <h:outputText value="#{miscMB.factura.cliente.nombre}"/>
                <h:outputText value="Factura: "/>
                <h:outputText value="#{miscMB.factura}"/>
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateGestionLabel_descripcion}" for="descripcion" />
                <p:inputText id="descripcion" value="#{miscMB.nuevaGestion.descripcion}" title="#{bundle.CreateGestionTitle_descripcion}" />

                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateGestionLabel_fechaLimiteGestion}" for="fechaLimiteGestion" />
                <p:calendar locale="es" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" id="fechaLimiteGestion" value="#{miscMB.nuevaGestion.fechaLimiteGestion}" title="#{bundle.CreateGestionTitle_fechaLimiteGestion}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateGestionRequiredMessage_fechaLimiteGestion}">

                </p:calendar>
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateGestionLabel_usuario}" for="usuario" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="usuario" value="#{miscMB.nuevaGestion.usuario}"  required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateGestionRequiredMessage_usuario}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{usuarioController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>

            </h:panelGrid>
            <br />
            <p:commandButton onsuccess="micalendario.update();PF('dlg1').hide();" action="#{gestionController.crearGestion()}" value="#{bundle.CreateGestionSaveLink}" >
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{gestionController.selected}" value="#{miscMB.nuevaGestion}"/>
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{gestionController.factura}" value="#{miscMB.factura}"/>
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{null}" target="#{miscMB.nuevaGestion}"/>
                <f:actionListener binding="#{miscMB.anularNuevaGestion()}"/>
                <f:actionListener binding="#{miscMB.agregarGestion(gestionController.selected)}"/>


            </p:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

This is where I call the dialog to display

```
<p:commandLink value="Asignar gestión" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();return false;" action="#{gestionController.preparar()}" rendered="#{miscMB.factura!=null}">
       <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{gestionController.factura}" value="#{miscMB.factura}"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

What happens is that both `<h:outputText value="#{miscMB.factura.cliente.nombre}"/>` and `<h:outputText value="#{miscMB.factura}"/>` values display the properties' last state.

For example, the first time an item selected and you call the dialog, the output is none, because the state is not set. Then, when you select another item and call the dialog, the output is the state last set, which is the previous item value.

Apparently, the setPropertyActionListener in the commandLink is called after the dialog is closed or it executes an action, but not when the commandLink is clicked.

So, how can I set the properties before the dialog frame is displayed?

Comment: could you try using `oncomplete="PF('dlg1').show();"` instead of `onclick="PF('dlg1').show();return false;"`?

Comment: @tt_emrah Tried both oncomplete and on success... did not work :(

Comment: also, can you change `action="#{gestionController.preparar()}"` to `actionListener="#{gestionController.preparar()}"` please?

Comment: and do it while using `oncomplete` or `onsuccess` please, not `onclick`.